# Proof of recurrence relation of first kind Stirling Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

The Stirling numbers of the first kind satisfy the recurrence relation
$$s(n +1, k) = s(n, k −1)−n · s(n, k),$$if $n ≥ k ≥ 0.$

What will be the proof this statement$?$

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Which definition of these numbers do you have?

Comment: It depends on your definition of *Stirling numbers of the first kind*. If your  definition is related to the coefficients of $(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+k)$, that is quite trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went to wikipedia.

The Stirling numbers of the first kind,
$s(n, k)$,
are defined by

$(x)_n
=\sum_{k=0}^n s(n, k) x^k
$
where
$(x)_n
=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (x-i)
$.

Then
$(x)_{n+1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} s(n+1, k) x^k
$.

But

$\begin{array}\\
(x)_{n+1}
&=(x)_n(x-n)\\
&=(x-n)\sum_{k=0}^n s(n, k) x^k\\
&=x\sum_{k=0}^n s(n, k) x^k-n\sum_{k=0}^n s(n, k) x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n s(n, k) x^{k+1}-n\sum_{k=0}^n s(n, k) x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} s(n, k-1) x^{k}-n\sum_{k=0}^n s(n, k) x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} s(n, k-1) x^{k}+s(n, n)x^{n+1}-n(s(n, 0)+\sum_{k=1}^n s(n, k) x^k)\\
&=s(n, n)x^{n+1}-ns(n, 0)+\sum_{k=1}^{n} (s(n, k-1) x^{k}-n s(n, k)) x^k\\
\end{array}
$

Equating coefficients gives
$s(n+1, 0) = -ns(n, 0),
s(n+1, n+1) = s(n, n),$
and,
for $1 \le k \le n$,
$s(n+1,k)
=s(n, k-1) x^{k}-n s(n, k)
$.